# ¿Cómo aplicar script a un dataset para cada categoría presente en un solo paso)?

Tags: r, filtro

Tengo dos bases de datos en las que cada fila representa un individuo, y cada columna determinados atributos, siendo de interés la identificación del individuo, y la ciudad de residencia:

```
df1 = data.frame(ID_INDIVIDUO = c("individo_1", "individo_2", "individo_3", "individo_4", "individo_5", "individo_6", "individo_7"), 
                ciudad = c("Ciudad_A", "Ciudad_A", "Ciudad_B", "Ciudad_C", "Ciudad_C", "Ciudad_D", "Ciudad_A"))

df2 = data.frame(ID_INDIVIDUO = c("individo_1", "individo_4", "individo_5", "individo_6", "individo_7"), 
                ciudad = c("Ciudad_A", "Ciudad_C", "Ciudad_C", "Ciudad_D", "Ciudad_A"))
```

Me interesa saber qué individuos del df1 ya no están presentes en el df2, y contarlos. Para ello, se me ocurre hacer:

```
Individuos_df2 <- df2 %>%
  pull(ID_INDIVIDUO)

Individuos_df1_NO_en_df2 <- df1 %>%
  filter(!ID_INDIVIDUO %in% Individuos_df2)

Conteo <- Individuos_df1_NO_en_df2 %>% count()
```

Pero ahora, lo que me interesaría sería hacer el mismo análisis por separado para cada ciudad. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo sin tener que aplicar un filtro y correr el código una y otra vez para cada ciudad? Me imagino que debe ser algo relativamente sencillo, pero soy bastante nueva en esto y no logro darme cuenta.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma bien simple podría ser:

- Filtrar los elementos no coincidentes
- Agrupar por ciudad y contar la cantidad

Algo así:

```
df1 %>% 
  anti_join(df2,
            by=c("ciudad", "ID_INDIVIDUO")) %>% 
  group_by(ciudad) %>% 
  summarize(n=n())
```

---

Con `df1 %>% anti_join(df2, by=c("ciudad", "ID_INDIVIDUO"))` obtenemos las filas no coincidentes entre en ciudad e individuos, luego solo resta agrupar por ciudad y contar.

Comment: Gracias Patricio, no conocía el anti_join! Y muy efectivo y simple usar group_by y summarize, lo voy a tener en cuenta en el futuro. Aprovecho a consultar: no me queda claro en este caso para qué se hace el inner_join, ¿sería lo mismo hacer directamente `df1 %>% anti_join(df2, by=c("ID_INDIVIDUO")) %>% group_by(ciudad) %>% summarize(n=n())` ? Entiendo que así se estaría seleccionando los individuos que no coinciden, es decir, no están presentes en ambas bases, ¿verdad?

Comment: Me he dado cuenta con tu comentario, lo escribo así por una idiosincrasia personal, me resulta más fácil de entender si busco las filas que no están en  el conjunto de las coincidencias, pero efectivamente, en este caso el `anti_join(df2` funcionaría bien, entiendo que aún así deberías hacer que el by sea por ciudad e individuo,.